# gulp-shell throwing Error: write EPIPE while using pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, npm, gulp

I am using [`gulp-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to execute a `pg_dump` command to create a simple dump of my postgres database. The command `gulp postgres-dump` will create the dump successfully but sometimes it will throw the following error after I enter the password and hangs for a while.

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:775:14)
```

This is my (simplified) `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp                = require('gulp'),
    plugins             = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

    plugins.shell       = require('gulp-shell');

var dbDumpPath = 'db_dumps/';

/**
 * Create postgres dump of the database
 */
gulp.task('postgres-dump', function() {
    return gulp.src('*.js', {read: false})
           .pipe(plugins.shell([
                'pg_dump database_name > ' + dbDumpPath +'database_bak.sql -h example.com -U databaseuser'
            ]));
});
```

I am able to run the `pg_dump` command in the command line without issue. Just to be clear, the db dump DOES happen even though the error sometimes occurs.

How am I able to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [gulp-shell docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) again, I decided to try the shorthand version. Which ended up working and not throwing any errors.

```
gulp.task('postgres-dump', plugins.shell.task([
  'pg_dump database_name > ' + dbDumpPath +'database_bak.sql -h example.com -U databaseuser'
]));
```